# Como pasar dato seleccionado en jComboBox (dentro de un JOptionPane) a un formulario que lo procesará luego

Tags: java, jframe, joptionpane

tengo un problema en el flujo lógico de una pequeña aplicación, inicialmente estoy capturando un dato en un jComboBox así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que mi programa espere que ese dato (asociado a una variable) este seleccionado y luego necesito que se pase a un JFrame, el cual hace un despliegue grafico, basado en ese valor de esa variable que se capturó antes en el jComboBox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro que se espere a seleccionar, y pasar el valor seleccionado, no obstante cuando lo hago con un *JOptionPane.showInputDialog* si se da la lógica que necesito y la aplicación trabaja

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El jComboBox es lo primero que aparece y está dentro de un jOptionPane, ahí la aplicación debe esperar a que el usuario seleccione un valor entero de la lista desplegable, una vez seleccionado, este valor es una variable global en mi main, que luego se pasa a un proceso grafico que despliega un JFrame que se abre a continuación. Como anoté antes, si capturo ese valor, de esa variable, con un JOptionPane.showInputDialog funciona, per quiero que sea con desde una lista desplegable. Gracias por los aportes.